# I can't link javascript files as commonjs modules

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, commonjs

I have:

- `test.json` - contains the content to be uploaded into the HTML page
- `test.js` - contains the function that sends an Ajax request to the JSON file, parses, compiles with Handelbars Temlate and puts the content into the HTML page (using innerHTTML).
- `addcontent.js` - javascript file which calls the function from the `test.js` file
- `index.html` - contains the Handlebars Template, Div
  where the content will be placed after processing, and a link to the
  `addcontent.js`.

Everything works, if inside `index.html` there is a link directly to `test.js`.
Everything works if I wrap the code inside `test.js` in a function with variables and call this function in the same file.

But if I call this function from `addcontent.js` and connecting `addcontent.js` and `test.js` using commonJS module approach, it does not work.
Probably I made a syntax mistake somewhere, but I don't see it.

*P.S. I use `NodeJS`, `NPM`, `HTTP-server` and I'm going to merge all javascript files using `browserify` after all*

```js
//test.js 

module.exports = function addContent (jsonDir, templId, finId){
function sendGet(callback) {
    /* create an AJAX request using XMLHttpRequest*/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    /*reference json url taken from: http://www.jsontest.com/*/

    /* Specify the type of request by using XMLHttpRequest "open", 
       here 'GET'(argument one) refers to request type
       "http://date.jsontest.com/" (argument two) refers to JSON file location*/
    xhr.open('GET', jsonDir);

    /*Using onload event handler you can check status of your request*/
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        } else {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    };

    /*Using onerror event handler you can check error state, if your request failed to get the data*/
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        alert("Network Error");
    };

    /*send the request to server*/
    xhr.send();
}

//For template-1
var dateTemplate = document.getElementById(templId).innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(dateTemplate);

sendGet(function (response) {
    document.getElementById(finId).innerHTML += template(response);
})
}
```

```css
/* test.json */

{
   "time": "03:47:36 PM",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1471794456318,
   "date": "08-21-2016-123",
    "test": "lalala 123"
}


/* addcontent.js */

var addContent = require('./test');

addContent("json/test.json", "date-template", 'testData');
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="handlebars-v4.0.5(2).js"></script>
</head>

    
<body>
    
    <!-- template-1 -->
<div id="testData"></div>
<script id="date-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  Date:<span> <b>{{date}}</b> </span> <br/> Time: <span><b>{{time}}</b>
    
    </span>
</script>
    
    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="addcontext.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `it does not work` - have you done **any** debugging at all? e.g. your browser probably has `developer tools` which **will** assist in at least *basic* debugging of your "code" - did you notice the error in the snippet you posted? do you expect snippet you posted should run as a snippet here?

Comment: @JaromandaX I checked  test.js and addcontent.js using online validators, they mostly warn about Ajax and CommonJS elements that do not fit into a standard javascript syntax.

Comment: that's very interesting information nobody asked for - you **do** load commonjs in your page, right? because, if you don't, you've just spotted your first mistake - really, the **developer** tools console is a wealth of information for any **developer** of web content

Comment: @JaromandaX the snippet I posted, of course will not work here since I put the content of several JS and JSON files in the area for CSS. I used the snippet, just to make it easier to review the code.

Comment: Cool - you still haven't looked in your browsers developer tools console to check for any errors there - the only thing I said that could possibly help both you and us (to help you) and you refuse to do any *basic* debugging before asking for help to fix a problem that you can't even provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example of - do you not understand what the browser developer tools are?

Comment: @JaromandaX `any debugging at all` - I thought that code validation process is a stage that determines the need for the debugging process, isn't it? But thank you for the advice, I will also check my code, using developer tools.

Comment: I don't want you to "check your code" using developer tools, I want you to use developer tools to **debug** your code ... code can be valid syntax and still be riddled with bugs - you've checked syntax (good **first** step) but that doesn't guarantee error free execution

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for clarifying your thoughts, of course I want to facilitate the work of those who are going to help me, so I will use the developer tools.